# Android- How to drag a picture on a canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, draw

I need to drag an image like in a videogame. I have a few lines drawed and I need to drag it and see the lines drawed before "out" of the window. I give you two images trying to help to understand it.

Image before drag:

[image: Image before drag]

Then I touch the screen with my finger and I make a move to the top of the screen, so this three lines have to be upper than the initial image, like this:

[image: Image after drag]

I don't know how to do this "drag efect", can someone help me? This is not an image as a .jpg file, is three lines drawed with "drawLine" on a canvas into an imageView.

My onTouchEvent Code and my drawRectangle code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
{
     switch (event.getAction()) 
     {      
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();

            getFirstFoot();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            ammountX = event.getX() - startX;
            ammountY = event.getY() - startY;

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(ammountX, ammountY);
            //canvas.restore();

            imageView.invalidate();

            return true;    
        }           
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();
        }
     }      
     return true;   
}
```

drawRectagle code:

```
private void drawRectangle(boolean erase)
{
    buttonRed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buttonGree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buttonYellow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ascensorsininfo);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, x - (bitmap2.getWidth() / 2), y - bitmap2.getHeight(), new Paint());

    drawedPoints.add(String.valueOf(x - (bitmap2.getWidth() / 2)));
    drawedPoints.add(String.valueOf(y - bitmap2.getHeight()));

    imageView.invalidate();

    y -= bitmap2.getHeight();              
}
```

Any solution would be apreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Canvas.translate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29)

It will "move" everything you draw afterwards the ammount you say in x and y axis.

Don't forget to save and restore it, like:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(ammountX, ammountY);
// [draw your stuff here]
canvas.restore();
```

If your question is more towards how to detect the dragging effect, you have to Override your view's onTouchEvent method. Something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.DOWN){
        startX = event.getX();
        startY = event.getY();
        return true;
    }else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.MOVE){
        ammountX = event.getX() - startX;
        ammountY = event.getY() - startY;
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything on my application. I add my code in to my question and you can see it. Probably I'm doing it wrong. Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: As I see I didn't explain it good. You have to Override your `View`'s `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method, that's called by the Android system everytime the user touches the screen. Normally you would override it in the View that has the canvas. And then the `canvas.save()` `.translate()` and `.restore()` you don't put them when there's a touch event, but everytime you want to draw stuff to your canvas.