# How to move two Circles on Android Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

I can only move a circle in the **onTouchEvent** method

Another problem I noticed is that when you touch anywhere on the Canvas, the position of Circle One changes

This should ONLY happen when touching / dragging the Circle

It looks like Canvas only recognizes a touch

How can I solve this problem ?

```
public class Example extends View {    
    private Paint circleOne, circleTwo;

    float xCircleOne, yCircleOne, xCircleTwo, yCircleTwo;

    int radiusCircleOne = 100;
    int radiusCircleTwo = 50;

    public Example(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        circleOne = new Paint();
        circleTwo = new Paint();

        ...
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                xCircleOne = event.getX();
                yCircleOne = event.getY();

                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Circles
        canvas.drawCircle(xCircleOne, yCircleOne, radiusCircleOne, circleOne);
        canvas.drawCircle(xCircleTwo, yCircleTwo, radiusCircleTwo, circleTwo);
    }
}
```

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040732/android-how-to-drag-a-picture-on-a-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int xonTouch,yonTouch,xonMotion,yonMotion;
boolean trackStatus;
int xdistance=xCircleTwo-xCircleOne;
int ydistance=yCircleTwo-YCircleOne;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

      switch (event.getAction()) {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://getInitialCoordinates when when you Touch;
            xonTouch=event.getX();
            yonTouch=event.geyY();
//TO move only when touching and dragging
//check if these xonTouch and yonTouch are inside the circle by comparing the coordinates of circle if these lie inside cirlce return true to track motion else return false so the ACTION_MOVE is not triggered
i.e          if(condition)//condition=xonTouch and yonTouch lie inside circle.
            trackStatus=true;
else trackStatus=false;



            break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//to move circle two use following 
               xCircleOne = event.getX();
               yCircleOne = event.getY();
                xCircleTwo= xCircleOne+xdistance;
               yCircleTwo = yCircleOne+ydistance;
trackStatus=true;



               invalidate();
               break;
       }
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
trackStatus=false;
break;}

       return trackStatus;
   }
```

Comment: to check if point (x,y) lies inside a circle with centre (p,s) and radius r the condition should be  condition=x>(p-r)&&x<(p+r)&&y>(s-r)&&y<(s+r).    And that xonmotion=event.getX() and yonmotion=event.getY() in  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: and use the differnces xonmotion-xontouch and yonmotion-yontouch to see how much your finger(touch) has moved and use it for dragging and moving.

Comment: canvas.drawCircle(xCircleOne, yCircleOne, radiusCircleOne, circleOne);  in this (xCircleOne,yCircleOne) represent the centre of circle if you want to move the circle change these values when you want to move the circle accordingly.and third parameter radiusCircleOne is the radius.change this to change the size of circle.if you want to move the second circle change the values of second circle also accordingly.

Comment: Code -> [link](https://gist.github.com/jonathansilva/f4787895e6cd5b47eaedfd1b3010cd8b) I'm in the right way ? I'm going step by step

Comment: oh sorry i didnt see that properly replace xonFinger and yonFinger with xCircleOne and yCircleOne in the condition.

Comment: hahahaha. The circle moves with the other =( What I want is to move each one apart but the line remains between the two circles

Comment: u mean you want to move only the circle touch and drag ?if thats your problem its simple

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to move the two circles. In my question, I mentioned that I can only move the red circle :(